# How does AOSP on a dual sim smartphone handle data?

Tags: mobile-data, wifi-hotspot, sim-card, tethering, aosp

How does AOSP on a dual sim smartphone handle data? Does it provide the option to choose the SIM when I do tethering or use the native hotspot?

Comment: AFAIK tethering has nothing to do with how your device is connected to internet. Tethering works even if there is no mobile data or even if you have setup Wi-Fi as the source of internet. Access Point is created by `hostapd` while `dnsmasq` runs as `dhcp` and `dns` server. Rules to forward network traffic are defined using ketnel's `routing table` and `netfilter`. So the traffic flows through whatever connection of internet you have. But a ROM may add extra feature to choose SIM when tethering is turned on.

Comment: This is mostly a question about UI, not architecture. Ideally, I could pick which sim I wanted to use for data. Does the UI afford any feature like this?

Comment: Not in my knowledge, but neither too far from possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to digitalcitizenlife, you have two screens you can change this under the `Default Mobile Data` option,

[image]
[image]
[image]

There is also a [Huawei FAQ about this, *"Dual SIM settings
"*](http://consumer.huawei.com/minisite/newproGuide/egen/P9/faqs/detail/First_use02.htm)

Comment: I am not sure but the screenshots and the link seems to be all Huawei specific. How does this answer the question about dual-sim on AOSP?